# Array to string conversion in mysql while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my code,

```
  $result1 = "SELECT emp_id FROM employee where manager_id=".$userID;
            $array = mysql_query($result1);
            $cnt = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($array)) {
                 "emp_id: " . $row[0];
                 $myArrayOfemp_id[$cnt] = $row[0];
                 $cnt++;
            }
            var_dump($myArrayOfemp_id);

            $sql = "SELECT emp_id FROM emp_leaves WHERE emp_id='$myArrayOfemp_id' ORDER BY apply_date DESC";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

---

When I'am trying to use `$myArrayOfemp_id` variable in `$sql` query, It shows that error:

> Array to string conversion in..

How can I fix it?

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you.

Comment: Modified my answer, let me know if it works now.

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do right here, why you make $myArraOfempid as an array..

Comment: Use of `mysqli_*` will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert an array into a string in the following line:

```
$sql = "SELECT emp_id FROM emp_leaves 
WHERE emp_id='$myArrayOfemp_id' ORDER BY apply_date DESC";
```

`$myArrayOfemp_id` is an array. That previous line of code should be changed to:

```
$sql = "SELECT emp_id FROM emp_leaves 
WHERE emp_id={$myArrayOfemp_id[0]} ORDER BY apply_date DESC";
```

I placed `0` inside `{$myArrayOfemp_id[0]}` because I'm not sure what value want to use that is inside the array.

---

**Edited:**

After discussing what the user wanted in the question, it seems the user wanted to use all the values inside the array in the sql statement, so here is a solution for that specific case:

```
$sql = "SELECT emp_id FROM emp_leaves 
WHERE ";
foreach ($myArrayOfemp_id as $value)
{
    $sql .= " emp_id={$value) || ";
}
$sql .= "1=2";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I tried as your way, But it also make error as " Undefined offset:" How to make this error?

Comment: So that probably means you have another error in your code other than the one you mentioned about the array. What line of code is causing the error? the error message should include that information.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_leaves WHERE emp_id='{$myArrayOfemp_id[$cnt]}' ORDER BY apply_date DESC"; on that line

Comment: what is this line of code doing here: `   "emp_id: " . $row[0];`? You are not assinging the resulting string to anything, why?

Comment: I removed it, but still it make error which is " Undefined offset:" , Please let me know how to resolve all problems

Comment: @Chathurika I know what the problem is... it's the `[$cnt]`. What value inside `$myArrayOfemp_id` do you want to use in your sql statement?

Comment: I want to get all values that include in the array.

Comment: @Chathurika Hmmm I see... well you could make a loop that inserts the code into the sql statement to make a bunch of or conditions. I'll put an edit on my answer, just 1 second.

Comment: @Chathurika let me know if it's working now with the new code.

Comment: @Chathurika no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT emp_id FROM emp_leaves WHERE emp_id in 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(emp_id) FROM employee where manager_id=".$userID.") 
       ORDER BY apply_date DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

just change your query like above might solve your problem.

you can remove following code now. :)

`$result1 = "SELECT emp_id FROM employee where manager_id=".$userID;
            $array = mysql_query($result1);
            $cnt = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($array)) {
                 "emp_id: " . $row[0];
                 $myArrayOfemp_id[$cnt] = $row[0];
                 $cnt++;
            }
            var_dump($myArrayOfemp_id);`